# drupal default image field without "remove_button" on edit form drupal 7

Tags: forms, hooks, theming, javascript

I have created one event content type. On which I Have field_event_picture image field. Now what I want is, when user edit event form user will click on field_event_picture and browse popup comes up, without pressing remove button then again clink on browse button.

I have tried this with autoload module. But it will remove only upload button not works with edit form.

Comment: I guess you could add your own submit handler.
Create a hook_form_alter and set $form['submit'][] = YOUR_SUBMIT_HANDLER.
In your new submit handler you can check for an existing image, if true then replace. Else upload new.

Comment: @Akko I manage to hide remove image button using jquery code. But after clicking on image it is reloading page

Comment: Is it possible to save and remove image with ajax? without reloading page.